# What could be causing a sudden 404 error when navigating to routes on my Vue 3 JS test server?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, webserver

I am developing a project on vue 3 js. When I am working on my localhost, there is no error. I made all routes. When browser catches a error, it is redirected to my home page. When I run my project at test server, with buttons I can change route but when I change routes on browser's search bar or I refresh url on search bar I get 404 not found error. But I am sure that route is working and I can go that route in project with buttons. However I can't refresh or go other routes on search bar. It suddenly throws 404 error. It is too fast it is like throwing 404 error without looking at which page. It behaves like all page doesn't exist when you are refreshing or going some routes on search bar. I am new at vue 3 js or web development. This is my first project on outside of localhost. So I have no idea.

I am refreshing or going other routes on browsers search bar. I got 404 page not found error suddenly like it doesn't exist.I am expecting i can go or refresh url on search bar

Comment: What are you using for a web server?  As an SPA, there is only `index.html` that is actually served, whereas in MPAs there is an html page for every path. Most web servers by default treat web apps like an MPA, expecting a unique html file to exist based on the given URL path.  For SPAs you usually need to tell the web server to redirect *all* routes to "/" (your index.html file).  From there, your router code will handle everything.

Comment: I am using SPA. There ıs only `index.html` . How can i tell the web servet to redirect all router to my `index.html` file?

Comment: It depends on your web server

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your help. I am using IIS web server. I am going to try configure my web server. I hope it works .